# JSF 2 dataTable row index without dataModel

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, uirepeat

I've been using ui:repeat to generate tables. With ui:repeat it's easy to get the rows numbered using the `varStatus`. I'm depending on the row id's from varStatus when calling the backing bean to handle list navigation, for example moving an item up or down in the list.

Now I'd like to create a composite component that builds a customizable table with all functionality needed for marking rows, moving them up/down etc. To do this, the ui:repeat won't work as I can't see a way of handling different number of columns; I need to specify headings in one place and the body in another (and I've not reached the knowledge point where I can create a custom component). Therefore I went on to datatable instead, as using that means specifying the headers as facets at the same place as the body content.

That worked well until I noticed that for some reason there were no `varStatus` anymore. I have put a lot of work into handling list presentation without any need for a `datamodel` and I do not want to start using that. Is there any way that I can get the current row number as it is displayed in the table, without using `datamodel`?

Also I'm using viewScope and if I've understood correctly that means I cannot bind the dataTable to the bean.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just bind the table to the view itself instead of to a bean.

```
<h:dataTable binding="#{table}" ...>
```

Then you can use `#{table.rowIndex}` where necessary. E.g.

```
<h:column>#{table.rowIndex + 1}</h:column>
```

Note that the code is as-is and that the EL variable name `table` is fully to your choice.

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: I read another post where you had this as a solution, although I thought that the binding="#{table}" was some shorthand for binding to the bean. I didn't know this was possible. Thank you BalusC!

Comment: I thought exactly the same way as @nivis. Maybe because value of `var` attribute does NOT need EL statement, but value of `binding` attribute  DOES. I had prejudice that any named values inside the EL statement should already be declared (by myself), and I felt like giving some name to variable (eg. `table` , `rowItem`) should NOT happen with EL statements.

Comment: what is `table` "view itself", please?

Comment: I do not get it, `table.rowIndex` always -1 here. What is `#{table}`?

Comment: @Palo: code is as-is. Of course the `<h:column>` must go inside the `<h:dataTable>`. You can use any non-existent variable name you want such as `#{foo}`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/14911158

Comment: @BalusC many thanks. One of the mistakes I made was trying to use that in `id` attribute of `h:commandButton`, but that one does not accept EL at all. So now I have misused `tabindex` attribute for the purpose of passing a parameter to `actionListener`. My scenario is probably ill, but I have bunch of buttons in a table, which are all the same, but each corresponds to another row, so I'd like to know in the `actionListener` that is shared by all these buttons, which button was pressed (in which row).

Comment: I only had plain list of strings in the table, so decorating button with the row number would have helped. But now I have changed it to a list of compound object that has the row number and the original string, and thus I happen to avoid the `table.rowIndex` completely, because that did not work in `tabindex` neither. So now I misuse the `tabindex` for passing the parameter to the button's `actionListener`, but the row number comes from the list. I think I still do not understand what are you talking about and what this `table.rowIndex` means, where does it come from and how could it be used.

Comment: @Palo: `<h:dataTable binding>` refers a `HtmlDataTable` instance. It has [among others](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/2.3/apidocs/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlDataTable.html) a `getRowIndex()` method.

Comment: It does not work with Mojarra 2.1.7. The table is not displayed anymore. Instead, you have to use the "magic word" `table` without `binding`

Comment: @Marco: it will indeed fail when you store the variable in a scope broader than the request scope and therefore incorrectly reuse the very same component in all other views/states tied to the same bean (components are request scoped and never designed to be thread safe as that's otherwise way too expensive/inefficient). See the "See also" link in updated answer.

Comment: I checked the entire project for "table" and there's no other component that uses this variable, only `HTML` tables