# Binding multiple JSF dataTables to view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, binding, datatable, composite-component

In order to get the row numbers of a datatable I got an answer here that I could bind the dataTable directly to the view ([JSF 2 dataTable row index without dataModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633008/jsf-2-datatable-row-index-without-datamodel)).

I'm using that function in a composite component and there may be several of those in the same page. I believe that the binding makes it impossible to use more than one component on each page; is it possible to bind each table "separately" somehow?

Comment: Well you will bind each table on different managed bean, or on different properties of backing bean? Why would it be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a backing component class with an `UIData` property.

```
@FacesComponent("fooComponent")
public class FooComponent extends UINamingContainer {

    private UIData table;

    // +getter +setter
}
```

And bind it to `#{cc.table}` instead (the `#{cc}` refers the current backing component instance).

```
<cc:interface componentType="fooComponent">
    ...
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:dataTable binding="#{cc.table}" ...>
        <h:column>#{cc.table.rowIndex + 1}</h:column>
        ...
    </h:dataTable>
</cc:implementation>
```

Comment: Just noticed that I'm not able to use cc.table.RowIndex inside p:commandLink: <p:commandLink actionListener="#{bean.selectRow(cc.table.rowIndex)}"... I can see it beeing displayed in each table row, but it seems it's not available inside the actionListener.

Comment: Easier to use ui:repeat.

Comment: @Neuralrank: It appears that you've misread the question. The question asks explicitly about a data table.

Comment: @BalusC: Although your answer to the question is correct I believe it's not likely to be the best solution to the OP's actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ui:repeat instead, it has built in support via varStatus.index.

Comment: I doubt that the OP is aware that this functionality exists in ui:repeat.