# Get id from current row dataTable to link JSF Primefaces Java

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

How can i get Id of current Row p:dataTable primefaces to my link where is used this Id? Describe it (sorry for my English). My dataTable looks like on this picture: 
http://www.image-share.com/igif-2333-105.html 
When i click the button i want to get Id of row where is this button, for example row 1 have id 1, so when button 1 is clicked i must get ID = 1. Show how looks my link where need id: 
http://'serverAddress'/myApplication/PDF?type=document&id="+id" 
Variable id have type int and getters, setters in entity and bean. Button in JSF looks like below: 
  h:commandButton value="Print" action="#{printBean.print()}"/> 
Method 'Print' initiate my link. Any ideas how to do this? Thanks for help.

Comment: I think what he is looking for is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633008/jsf-2-datatable-row-index-without-datamodel in case of plain JSF.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `p:dataTable`'s `rowIndexVar` attribute.

> Name of the iterator to refer each row index

Whose iterator name can be used in EL to get the Row Id

For Example:
if `rowIndexVar="myId"` then you can access each row Index using that iterator name in EL using `#{myID}`.

Example:

```
<p:dataTable rowIndexVar="rowId" value="..." var="...">
    <p:column>
       <h:commandLink action="#{...}">
         <f:param name="id" value="#{rowId}" />
       </h:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: And how would I use the selected rowId in my bean function? I mean, I need a variable whose value is one when I click the button in first row (Or any other technique which would let me know the selected row in my table)

Answer (score 2):

Get `id` in bean

```
map<String,String> par_map = new HashMap<String,String>(); par_map=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

String id=par_map.get("id");
```