# how to generate an outputlink from database?

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

Im starting with jsf with icefaces and i need to do this
this is my mysql table

[image: links table]

I want to generate an outputlink for each row, thats what i did

[image: fail!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Mr @BalusC's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14633383/2459449), you can achieve that by :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.someList}" var="v" binding="#{someList}" rules="all">
     <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">titulos</f:facet> #{v.field1}
     </h:column>
     <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">link</f:facet> #{v.field2}
     </h:column>
     <h:column>
          <h:outputLink>www.newentity#{someList.rowIndex + 1}.com</h:outputLink>
     </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
```

*In case* the generated current website number does not depend to the row table, but rather to some current entity value, then replace the last column content by:

```
         <h:outputLink>www.newentity#{v.someIdentifiantField}.com</h:outputLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these `<h:outputLink >`, `<h:commandLink >` , or `<h:link>` components depending on your use case.