# What exactly is #{component} in EL?

Tags: jsf, el, uicomponents

According to https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4720, The `ComponentUtils.resolveWidgetVar(String expression, UIComponent component)` function is available in Primefaces since 2013. It can be used in EL by the `"#{p:widgetVarFromContext(searchExpression, component)}"` function.

This is useful in case of several components have the same id in different `NamingContainer`, but are still present in the same view. In this case, 
the `#{p:widgetVar(searchExpression)}` function only returns the last one found.

I don't understand however how to reference the `UIComponent` that must be passed as the second argument from EL. The above mentioned bug report suggests we can refer to it using `#{component}`. Can anyone provide me with an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `#{component}` is an implicit EL variable referring the [current `UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)) in EL scope (see also [implicit EL objects](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects)). You can usually only refer it in component's HTML attribute or in template text children.

E.g. in case of `<h:inputText>` it will reference an instance of [`UIInput`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) class which has among others an `isValid()` method.

```
<h:inputText id="foo" required="true"
    style="background: #{component.valid ? '' : 'pink'}"
    onclick="alert('Client ID of this component is #{component.clientId}');" />
```

You can also use `binding` attribute to let JSF during view build time put a reference to a component instance in the Facelet scope. This way the component reference will be available anywhere in the Facelet during view render time.

```
<script>alert('Client ID of foo component is #{foo.clientId}');</script>
<h:inputText binding="#{foo}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between client id generated by component.clientId and p:component()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539713/difference-between-client-id-generated-by-component-clientid-and-pcomponent/)
- [JSF component binding without bean property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168302/jsf-component-binding-without-bean-property)
- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Answer (score 3):

The `p:widgetVarFromContext` is useful when referring to a PrimeFaces widget inside a composite component. There could be more than one instance of your component on the same page. So writing `widgetVar="expression"` and `PF('expression')` is out of the question. There would be multiple widgets with the same name. It is then better to omit the `widgetVar` attribute and use the generated one which is unique because it is based on the `clientId`.

You can't use `#{p:widgetVar('expression')}` within your `<cc:implementation>` because it leads to a `Cannot find component for expression "expression" referenced from "j_id1"` error instead of the expected `PF('widget_expression')`.

But you can use `#{p:widgetVarFromContext('expression', cc)}` which will return something like `PF('widget_wrapperform_compositecomponent1_expression')`. The `cc` refers to the root of the composite component instance.

Comment: What a lovely answer.

Comment: Do note that the question is about `#{component}`, not `#{p:widgetVarFromContext()}`.

Comment: Indeed it does and your explanation is very complete. But  a google search for widgetVarFromContext brought me here time and again. My answer is the one I was looking for when I got here. So I just wrote this to help my future self.