# How to use today's date for a placeholder?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar, date-format, omnifaces

I got a `<p:calendar>` and want to use today's date as placeholder.

My attempt is to use OmniFaces `#{now}` in combination with `a:placeholder` for  this:

```
<p:calendar id="calendar" a:placeholder="#{now}" minHour="8" locale="de" 
maxHour="20" value="#{adminSeminarAlleBearbeitung.seminar.someproperty}" 
pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" />
```

Where `someproperty` is a `java.util.date`.
This is working so far, but I want to format the date like `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`of:formatDate()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Dates) function in EL:

```
<p:calendar ... a:placeholder="#{of:formatDate(now, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm')}" />
```

Or if you'd like to reuse calendar component's own pattern attribute:

```
<p:calendar ... a:placeholder="#{of:formatDate(now, component.pattern)}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" />
```

#### See also:

- [What exactly is #{component} in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035760/what-exactly-is-component-in-el-as-seen-in-pwidgetvarfromcontext-example)