# Accessing tag attribute within the same tag without using binding

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I'm writing a simple menu using PrimeFaces, and I'm wondering if I can access a tag attribute within itself. Let me explain:

```
...
<p:menuitem value="#{labels['menu.home']}" url="/pages/index.jsf"
            styleClass="#{view.viewId == '/pages/index.jsf' ? 'nav-selected-menuitem' : ''}"/>
...
```

Since this will be repeated for more pages, is there a way to do something of the sort:

```
<p:menuitem value="#{labels['menu.home']}" url="/pages/index.jsf"
            styleClass="#{view.viewId == url ? 'nav-selected-menuitem' : ''}"/>
```

Where `url` is the same `url` attribute in this p:menuitem tag.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component itself is available by [`#{component}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-).

So, this should do:

```
<p:menuitem ... url="/pages/index.jsf"
    styleClass="#{view.viewId == component.url ? 'nav-selected-menuitem' : ''}" />
```

Noted should be that this may fail if the component's renderer is badly implemented (i.e. it doesn't properly do [`pushComponentToEL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#pushComponentToEL-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-javax.faces.component.UIComponent-) as mandated by [`encodeBegin()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#encodeBegin-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-)). This is in turn worth an issue report at component library maintainer.

#### See also:

- [What exactly is #{component} in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035760/what-exactly-is-component-in-el/)

Comment: For some reason, calling `component` references `p:menuitem`'s parent, a `p:menu` component. I guess I could navigate to the `p:menuitem` component from there...

Comment: I'd say its renderer is badly implemented. This is not the first time I see it on a PrimeFaces component. Report an issue to make them aware and get them to fix it.

Comment: Thanks so much BalusC. As usual, you are the JSF god.