# Can a p:ajax component be used with p:outputLabel?

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I have a p:dataTable with some columns that contain p:outputLabel components.
I want to add p:ajax functionality so that if the user clicks on the outputLabel, I can call a server-side process to do some stuff - in the simple case it would gather some information and display that in a dialog.

I'm looking for something like this

```
  <p:outputLabel value="#{term.explanation}" >
      <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{backingBean.myListener}" />
  </p:outputLabel>
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, so I was wondering if someone might be able to give me a hint on how I can get something like this.  The constraint is that the dataTable needs to keep the p:outputLabel components - just need some way to ajaxify them.

Thanks in advance.
Dave J.

Comment: @Kukeltje sorry.. I see your comment just now. I was already writing my answer.

Comment: No problem. Am not able to write a full answer the coming days. 3 days of golfing in Delden. Only access to/on my mobile phone. So only short comments (as usual ;-))

Comment: Couldn't get the remote command to work in the context of a datatable column, but the command link option works.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{backingBean.myListener}"">
       <p:outputLabel value="#{term.explanation}" > </p:outputLabel>
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: This will add a link (and its style and behavior) to your HTML

Comment: This does the job if you add style="text-decoration: none" to suppress the underline.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`p:remoteCommand`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) here. You can use it to execute backing bean methods using JavaScript. For example:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="onLabelClick"
                 actionListener="#{backingBean.myListener}"/>
<p:outputLabel value="#{term.explanation}"
               onclick="onLabelClick()"/>
```

If you need to be able to know the specific `p:outputLabel` that was clicked you can add parameters to `p:remoteCommand` and use `#{component.clientId}` as the value.

See also:

- [Pass parameter to p:remoteCommand from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221495/pass-parameter-to-premotecommand-from-javascript)
- [What exactly is #{component} in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035760/what-exactly-is-component-in-el)