# How to know if component child is not valid Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using Primefaces 5.0 and I need to add class in element `<h:panelGroup>` when the `<p:inputText>` is not valid. I have the below code:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="form-group #{ VALIDATION HERE ? '' : 'has-error'}" >                               
  <p:outputLabel for="txtUserId" value="ID:"/>
  <p:inputText styleClass="form-control" id="txtUserId" required="true" value="#{userAction.user.id}">                                  
      <f:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" render="msgtxtUserId"/>
      <f:validateLength minimum="2" />                                  
  </p:inputText>
  <p:message for="txtUserId" id="msgTxtIdUsuario" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by not valid ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight: OP means containing an invalid value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You apparently already know that you can use [`UIInput#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) to check whether an input component is valid or not and that you could in EL use `#{component.valid}` for this. You only don't yet seem to realize that `#{component}` actually refers to an instance of the [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) class. If you inspect its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html), then you should have noticed a [`findComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent-java.lang.String-) method which you could use to find a child component by a search expression.

Knowing this, here's how you can achieve this:

```
<h:panelGroup ... styleClass="#{component.findComponent('txtUserId').valid ? '' : 'has-error'}">
    <p:inputText id="txtUserId" ... />
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [What exactly is #{component} in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035760/what-exactly-is-component-in-el/)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you come to the conclusion in your first sentence?