# Primefaces Wizard custom back/next button label

Tags: button, primefaces, label, wizard

i have a question regarding the back/next button label for primefaces wizard. It is possible to customize the navigation button label like the following example:

- Button label at step 0 -> Show button label text "Next 1"
- Button label at step 1 -> Show button label text "Next 2" and button back label "Back 1"
- Button label at step 2 -> Show button label text "Next 3" and button back label "Back 2"
- ...

Best regards,
Mux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the component has two attributes the nextLabel and backLabel.

https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/wizard?id=attributes

```
nextLabel   null    String  Label of next navigation button.
backLabel   null    String  Label of back navigation button.
```

Then do..

```xml
<p:wizard widgetVar="wgtWizard" nextLabel="Next #{component.step}" backLabel="Back #{component.step}">
```

But since the #component.step is not evaluated on every step you have to do it with JQuery JS code like this following:

```js
var wizard = PF('wgtWizard');
var stepIndex = wizard.getStepIndex(wizard.currentStep);
wizard.nextNav.find('.ui-button-text').text('Next ' + stepIndex);
wizard.backNav.find('.ui-button-text').text('Back ' + (stepIndex-1));
```

Just execute that JS code on the wizard 'onback' and 'onnext' JS methods.

Comment: I think those labels are not updated automatically when you go the next or previous tab

Comment: You might be right.  Then it would be an enhancement request or the user will have to do it with some clever Jquery code to update the labels.

Comment: Also, you might want to use the implicit EL object `component`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035760/what-exactly-is-component-in-el

Comment: Thanks I never knew about #{component}!  I just updated my answer.

Comment: Also you are right its only evaluated when the component first renders not on every step so I updated my answer with a Jquery solution.